# Element with name not being sent with form data via POST

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to submit my modal title as post data, however it isn't being sent.
I have given the element a name attribute. Elements in the modal body are submitting as I would expect. Trying to submit the element whose name is "editModalTitle" below

HTML:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <form action="/editItem" method="post" id ="editModalForm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" name="eModalTitle"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-group">
              <label>Quantity:</label>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                      <select class="form-control" id="qtSelect">
                        <option>Set to</option>
                        <option>Add</option>
                        <option>Subtract</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col" id= "qtD">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qt" name="quantityTB" placeholder="Quantity">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="prD">
          <label>Price:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pr" name="priceTB" placeholder="Enter new price here...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label>Notes:</label>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                      <select class="form-control" id="ntSelect">
                        <option>Set notes to:</option>
                        <option>Add to notes:</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ntInput" name="notesTB"placeholder="Enter notes here...">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label>Location:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loc" name="locationTB" placeholder="Enter new location here...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" id="eSvBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Form data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKbvZ.png)

Edit 1: Added full html for modal.

Comment: Please provide the full code and post action (jquery form submit or button)

Comment: Have you tried using a read-only input instead of h5?

Comment: Or you can add id to the tag <h5> whitch contain the title you want to submit and before submit get it using jQuery like: var titleToSubmit = $('#h5_id').attr("name");
Or if you need to have it more generic not using unique id, you can assign to the <h5 tag a classname> and get the name attribute using: var titleToSubmit = $('.h5_class_of_choice').attr("name");

Comment: I haven't tried using read-only input, what is the advantage of using that? And Sigma, how do I submit data that is not in form to server?

Comment: And Sigma, how do I submit data that is not in form to server?

you have a submit button and in this case when you click on submit button using form action, you are submitting to the action page all data inside <form> and </form>

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form action="/editItem" method="post" id ="editModalForm">

            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" name="eModalTitle"></h5>
                        <!-- hidden value for modal title to post -->
                        <input type="hidden" id="Modal_title_to_post" name="Modal_title_to_post" value="eModalTitle">
                        <!-- hidden value for modal title to post -->
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Quantity:</label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <select class="form-control" id="qtSelect">
                                    <option>Set to</option>
                                    <option>Add</option>
                                    <option>Subtract</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col" id= "qtD">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qt" name="quantityTB" placeholder="Quantity">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" id="prD">
                        <label>Price:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pr" name="priceTB" placeholder="Enter new price here...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Notes:</label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <select class="form-control" id="ntSelect">
                                <option>Set notes to:</option>
                                <option>Add to notes:</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ntInput" name="notesTB"placeholder="Enter notes here...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Location:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loc" name="locationTB" placeholder="Enter new location here...">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="eSvBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated code with hidden value for the modal title :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the title is still not being submitted even with this updated html. Thanks a bunch for taking the time to help me btw.

Comment: FredF, the submit button post just all the data contained in the <input> tags and not paragraphs or span or in your case h5 tags, if you want to submit other data different from <input> you must get these data using jQuery and add the data as a + parameter to the submit

Comment: Ah thank you for the explanation! I have finally got it working.

Comment: you are welcome, the updated code also post the title, check it